# Как отформатировать строку и сделать ровную таблицу

Tags: c

Есть клиент, который запрашивает информацию у сервера. Получает данные с помощью `recv()`
Например:

```
char buffer[1024];
if (recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == -1)
  error_wrap("recv() returned negative value");
```

В буфере лежат данные о пользователях, которые выглядят так:

```
"Anna 408 32 02:23\nUser1 371 21 02:37\nEgor 363 37 02:52\n\000\"
```

Хотелось бы сделать таблицу вывода с этими данными, например:

```
Nickname   WPM   Errors   Time
Anna       408   32       02:23
User1      371   21       02:37
Egor       363   37       02:52
```

Мое решение довольно простое:

```
for (int i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; i++) {
 printf("%c", buf[i]);
 if (buf[i] == ' ')
   printf("%10c", ' ');
}
```

Только в выводе я получаю:

```
Anna           408           32           02:23
User1           371           21           02:37
Egor           363           37           02:52
```

Как можно подровнять колонки? Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самом примитивном варианте можно сделать как-то так:

```
for (char *s=buf; s;) {
  bool add_endl = false;
  char *next = strpbrk(s, " \n");

  if(next) {
    char sep = *next ;
    *next=0;
    printf("%-15s%c", s, sep);
  }
  s = next+1;
}
```

Основные идеи:

- Ищем конец текущего поля и заменяем его нулём.
- Выводим всю строку сразу с помощью `printf`, задав размер поля (`15`) и, по желанию, выравнивание по левому краю (`-`).

Обычные расширения:

- Разная ширина для каждого столбца — делается или просто добавлением счётчика в цикл, или предварительным парсингом всей строки, а потом выводом за один `printf()`
- Автоматический подсчёт ширины столбцов — придётся делать в 2 прохода: сначала найти максимальную ширину столбца, а затем выводить. Стоит также освежить память, как работает динамическое задание ширины (`"%*s"`) в `printf()`.
- Вывод без модификации исходного буфера — тоже самое, что и выше но с использованием спецификатора `"%.s"`, примерно так:

  ```
  printf("%-15.*s%c", next-s, s, sep);
  ```
- Учёт ширины терминала — требуются системно-зависимые функции

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант, создаем некую функцию, цель которой расставить нужное количество пробелов в каждой строке.

1. Вы определяетесь с **минимальным** количеством пробелов между столбцами (допустим 6).
2. Смотрите, какая строка в каком столбце длиннее всего. Ставите туда 6 пробелов.
3. Проходитесь по этому столбцу по всем строкам и из длинны самой длинной строки столбца вычитаете длину текущей строки текущего столбца.

и т.д.
Например:

```
"Anna 408 32 02:23\nUser1 371 21 02:37\nEgor 363 37 02:52\n\000\"

Для удобства представим как

Anna 408 32 02:23
User1 371 21 02:37
Egor 363 37 02:52
```

Берем первый столбец. Самая длинная строка имеет 5 символов (**User1**).
Нам нужно расстояние между столбцами 6 пробелов (минимум).
Ставим после **User1** 6 пробелов.
**Anna** и **Egor** - 4 символа, а **User1** имеет 5 символов, значит 5 - 4 = 1. Нам нужно 6 пробелов в каждой строке **минимум**, а значит 1 + 6 = 7.
Ставим 7 пробелов после **Anna** и **Egor**.

Таким образом до второго столбца в каждой строке будет ровно 11 символов.

```
Anna       408 32 02:23
User1      371 21 02:37
Egor       363 37 02:52
```

После, анализируйте так же каждый столбец.
Может это и не лучший способ, но он довольно прост.